# Non-rowwise method to change multiple values in columns if present in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

In the example df below, for each row I want to determine if any values in b1:b3 are in a1:a3. If a match is not found, then change the unmatched b1:b3 value to NA. Note that the number of a and b columns in df may vary but the naming convention remains the same:

```r
df <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 12L, 17L, 44L, 55L, 90L), 
                     b1 = c(55L,17L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 12L), 
                     b2 = c(NA, 44L, 44L, 17L, NA, 17L),
                     b3 = c(NA, 90L, 90L, 90L, NA, 44L), 
                     a1 = c(55L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 12L), 
                     a2 = c(NA, 44L, 44L, 17L, NA, 28L), 
                     a3 = c(NA, 90L, NA, 90L, NA, 44L)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Desired output:

```
  row b1 b2 b3 a1 a2 a3
1   1 55 NA NA 55 NA NA
2  12 17 44 90 17 44 90
3  17 12 44 NA 12 44 NA
4  44 12 17 90 12 17 90
5  55  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
6  90 12 NA 44 12 28 44
```

I can achieve the desired output with the following for loop:

```
acols <- grep("^a", colnames(df))
bcols <- grep("^b", colnames(df))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  for(j in bcols) {
    
    if(df[i, j] %in% df[i, acols]) {
      
      next
      
    } else {
      
      df[i, j] <- NA
      
    }
      
  }

}
```

but I'm looking for a more efficient method as the real data are much larger. Does the `tidyverse` or base R have an alternative to this? I've searched for `across()` approaches but I couldn't translate any solutions to my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base solution that should be quite fast:

```
acols <- grep("^a", colnames(df))
bcols <- grep("^b", colnames(df))

df[bcols] = lapply(
  df[bcols], 
  \(bb) {
    bb[rowSums(bb == df[acols], na.rm = TRUE) == 0] = NA_integer_
    bb
  })

df
#   row b1 b2 b3 a1 a2 a3
# 1   1 55 NA NA 55 NA NA
# 2  12 17 44 90 17 44 90
# 3  17 12 44 NA 12 44 NA
# 4  44 12 17 90 12 17 90
# 5  55  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
# 6  90 12 NA 44 12 28 44
```

I scaled your data up to 500k rows, and on that dataset this approach runs about 50x faster using 1/50 of the memory. I suspect the differences will be bigger as the number of columns increases.

```
single_loop = function(df){
  df[bcols] = lapply(
  df[bcols], 
  \(bb) {
    bb[rowSums(bb == df[acols], na.rm = TRUE) == 0] = NA
    bb
  })
  df
}

double_loop = function(df){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    for (j in bcols) {
      if (df[i, j] %in% df[i, acols]) {
        next
      } else {
        df[i, j] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
  df
}
```

```
df_big = df[sample(1:nrow(df), size = 5e5, replace = TRUE)]

bench::mark(
  op = double_loop(df_big),
  gregor = single_loop(df_big)
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   
# 1 op          624.8ms  624.8ms      1.60     381MB     9.60     1     6      625ms <df [6 ×…
# 2 gregor       12.8ms   13.4ms     48.5     7.63MB     9.33    26     5      536ms <df [6 ×…
# # … with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
# Warning message:
# Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check for values in any position you can round-trip pivot the data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  mutate(grp = substr(name, 1L, 1L),
         value = replace(value, !(value[grp == "b"] %in% value[grp == "a"])[1:n()], NA), 
         grp = NULL,
         .by = row) %>%
  pivot_wider()
  
# A tibble: 6 × 7
    row    b1    b2    b3    a1    a2    a3
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    55    NA    NA    55    NA    NA
2    12    17    44    90    17    44    90
3    17    12    44    NA    12    44    NA
4    44    12    17    90    12    17    90
5    55     1    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
6    90    12    NA    44    12    28    44
```

If it's ok to check by column pairs, you could do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(replace(pick(b1:b3), pick(a1:a3) != pick(b1:b3) | is.na(pick(a1:a3)), NA))

  row b1 b2 b3 a1 a2 a3
1   1 55 NA NA 55 NA NA
2  12 17 44 90 17 44 90
3  17 12 44 NA 12 44 NA
4  44 12 17 90 12 17 90
5  55  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
6  90 12 NA 44 12 28 44
```

Comment: My example data do suggest that pairwise is an option, but it's likely it won't be an option in the real data. Great to know the pairwise option though, and the `tidyverse` option too. I find the round-trip method the most intuitive.

Comment: I agree that the round trip method is very tidy, but it is slow and memory intensive. I just added it to my benchmark. I got tired of waiting with 500k rows, so I ran at 50k rows. At that scale, the pivot-check-unpivot took 1.4 seconds, the double loop in the post 0.16 seconds, and my lapply-rowsum 0.002 seconds. Pivoting is expensive. Here, you have to pivot **and** unpivot, which is nice for readability but terrible for performance.

Comment: @GregorThomas - right you are, not the best approach when there are few columns.  I imagine its comparative performance would improve as the number of columns increased.

Comment: On that, the pivot approach becomes more memory efficient than the single loop if the `a` and `b` sets have about 20 columns each, and both faster and significantly more memory efficient at about 40 columns each, irrespective of row size.

Comment: Interesting! I'm quite surprised by that, I'll have to give it some thought to adjust my intuition there.